# I can't cached a message before deleting itit

Tags: discord.js

first I want to apologize for my English, I use a translator.

So I would like to cache a message before I delete it, so I can retrieve its contents and display it in a ".  log"

I already have a code that allows me to cache all the messages in a channel, but it only works if you add a new message to the channel in question.

```
client.on("messageDelete", messageDelete  => require("./events/messagesDel.js")(client, messageDelete));

const config = require("../config.json");
module.exports = (client, message) => {
        if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return; {
                if (message.author.bot) return; {
                        if (message.content.startsWith(`${config.prefix}`)) return; {
                                client.logger_messages.log('info', `[MESSAGE] - [DELETE] - | Message id : (${message.id}) | Message author : ${message.author.username}(${message.author.tag})| Message content :  ⏩ |  ${message.content} | ⏪ `+ `| channel-name: #` + message.channel.name);
                        }
                }
        }
};
```

And here is the error I get :

[14/03/2022, 20:44:13] - [ERROR] - Cannot read properties of null (reading 'bot')

Answer (score -1):

```
client.on("messageDelete", (messageDelete) =>
  require("./events/messagesDel.js")(client, messageDelete)
);

const config = require("../config.json");
module.exports = (client, message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${config.prefix}`)) return;
  {
    client.logger_messages.log(
      "info",
      `[MESSAGE] - [DELETE] - | Message id : (${message.id}) | Message author : ${message.author.username}(${message.author.tag})| Message content :  ⏩ |  ${message.content} | ⏪ ` +
        `| channel-name: #` +
        message.channel.name
    );
  }
};
```